# Spring Boot actuator for backend application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I use Spring-boot 2.2.x for my backend application - spring-kafka + streams. My service will be deployed in Kubernetes as Docker image. I would like to add `spring-boot-starter-acutator`, but as I checked, from Spring-boot 2.x actuator requires `spring-boog-starter-web`. And there is a question what is a proper way to use actuator over http and use http server only actuator - `management` scope/context?
I know that I can use `jmx` instead of `http` but I would prefer http.

Comment: I would say no app web controlers = no problem

Comment: This package makes sense if used by an external party or device. Like: service discover or Kubernetes probes.

Comment: @Numichi yes we will use Kubernetes probes, so I would like to use actuator.